# MongoDb/php Get max id value on a collection

Tags: php, php-mongodb

I want to get the max id value on a collection.

How do I convert the mongoDb query:

```
db.tweets.find({},{id:1}).sort({id:-1}).limit(1)
```

to Mongo Query Language Statement using PHP?

I'm trying

```
$db->tweets->find(
    array(),
    array("id"=>1)
)->sort(array("id"=> -1))->limit(1);
```

but that doesn't work.

Comment: some questions * any error?
* is `$db->tweets` a MongoCollection object?
* are you getting `id`, not `_id`?

Comment: @user1159947: Kindly remember to accept and upvote answers that are found to be correct.

Answer (score 3):

I checked this and it works for me:

```
$val = $db->myCollection->find(array(), array('_id' => 1))->sort(array('_id' => -1))->limit(1);
```

The error in your code is that it should be "_id" and not "id". Also, I hope $db->tweets is a MongoCollection object and you have ensured this. Hope this helps.

Comment: Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method MongoDB\Driver\Cursor::sort()